# Apple Keyboards USB codes

Tags: keyboard, usb, reverse-engineering, wireshark

Do you know if Apple's keyboards use same usb coding as in this pdf:
http://www.mindrunway.ru/IgorPlHex/USBKeyScan.pdf
If not, then could someone post proper coding table for apple's usb keyboards?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that Apple's keyboards work with non-Apple computers, so they should implement the standardized USB Human Interface Device (HID) specification.  The key codes for that specification are found in the HID Usage Tables, table 12:

http://www.usb.org/developers/hidpage/Hut1_12v2.pdf